# Get specific text from a string java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I m working with strings in java script, for e.g if i have the below string:

```
str = "miniprofile-container http://www.linkedin.com/miniprofile?vieweeID=8573&context=anet&view"
```

i want the ID number "8573" from this type of strings. They are of different length but have the same struct as the above. So kindly help me in achieving it.

I may use the strcpy function, but it will not be a generic approach

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "miniprofile-container http://www.linkedin.com/miniprofile?vieweeID=8573&context=anet&view";
var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
var matches = str.match(pattern); //8573
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qex8J/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this if you don't want/need to use regex:

```
var str = "miniprofile-container http://www.linkedin.com/miniprofile?vieweeID=8573&context=anet&view";
    var s1 = str.indexOf("vieweeID=")+"vieweeID=".length;
    var matches = str.substring(s1,str.indexOf("&context"))

alert(matches);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qex8J/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var vieweeID = str.split('vieweeID=')[1].split('&')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/vieweeID\=(.*?)\&/)[1]
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKpJu/)